# bsplus: Carousel for dynamic number of plots in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, carousel, plotly

I am trying to create an application where a user selection determines the number of plots to be placed into a carousel. I have a MWE below, where a user "selects" anywhere between 1-10 of the lines in the parallel coordinate plot on the left. After doing so, on the right, 1-10 plots are created (one for each of the lines the user selected). This all seems to be working, and the dynamic number of plots are stored in a tagList() object.

With larger datasets, the number of lines the user can select can be large and the output plots can look crowded. Hence, I am trying to put the output plots into a carousel. Currently, I have all output plots in a carousel - but they are all shoved into the first page of the carousel.

I would be grateful to hear any advice on how I can tweak this MWE so that each page of the carousel only contains one of the output plots.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(bsplus)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),

  sidebarPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
    bs_carousel(id = "tabPrev", use_indicators = TRUE) %>%
      bs_append(content = uiOutput("plots"))
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  set.seed(1)
  dat <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID",1:10), A.1 = runif(10), A.2 = runif(10), A.3 = runif(10), B.1 = runif(10), B.2 = runif(10), B.3 = runif(10))
  dat$ID <- as.character(dat$ID)

  # Convert DF from scatterplot to PCP
  datt <- data.frame(t(dat))
  names(datt) <- as.matrix(datt[1, ])
  datt <- datt[-1, ]
  datt[] <- lapply(datt, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
  setDT(datt, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
  colnames(datt)[1] <- "x"
  dat_long <- melt(datt, id.vars ="x" )
  dat_long <- separate(dat_long, x, c("group", "rep"), remove=FALSE)
  dat_long$group <- factor(dat_long$group)

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(dat_long, x= ~x, y= ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', color = ~variable) %>% layout(dragmode="box", showlegend = FALSE)
  })

  d <- reactive(event_data("plotly_selected"))

  observeEvent(d(),{
  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
    output$plots <- renderUI({

    lengthY <- reactive((length(unique(d()$curveNumber))))
    if (lengthY()<1){
      plot_output_list <- list()
    }
    else{
      plot_output_list <- lapply(1:lengthY(), function(i) {
        plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
        plotlyOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
      })
    }

    # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
    # to display properly.
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })
  })

  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page.
  observeEvent(d(),{
    lengthY <- reactive(length(unique(d()$curveNumber)))
    for (i in 1:lengthY()) {
      # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
      # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
      # of when the expression is evaluated.
      local({
        my_i <- i
        curveY <- reactive(d()$curveNumber[my_i])
        plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

        ax <- list(title = "", showticklabels = TRUE)
        ay <- list(title = "Read Count")
        indDat <- as.data.frame(dat_long[variable %in% dat[curveY()+1,]$ID])
        g1 <- levels(indDat$group)[1]
        g2 <- levels(indDat$group)[2]
        g1m <- mean(filter(indDat, group==g1)$value)
        g2m <- mean(filter(indDat, group==g2)$value)

        output[[plotname]] <- renderPlotly({
          indDat %>% plot_ly(x = ~group, y = ~value, type = "scatter", marker = list(size = 10), color = ~group, colors = "Set2", hoverinfo = "text", text = paste0("Read count = ", format(round(indDat$value, 2), nsmall = 2))) %>% layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ay, legend = list(x = 0.35, y = -0.26)) %>% add_segments(x = g1, xend = g2, y = g1m, yend = g2m, showlegend = FALSE, line = list(color='#000000')) %>% add_trace(x = g1, y= g1m, showlegend = FALSE, hoverinfo = "text", text = paste0("Mean Read Count = ", round(g1m, digits = 2)), marker = list(color='#000000')) %>% add_trace(x = g2, y= g2m, showlegend = FALSE, hoverinfo = "text", text = paste0("Mean Read Count = ", round(g2m, digits = 2)), marker = list(color='#000000'))
        })
      })
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this is embedding the `bs_carousel` inside the `renderUI`. It does work but I couldn't manage to remove the `plots` object totally, which sometimes plots... If I remove it, only the first plot appears in the carousel.

1- Change the `ui` to :

```
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),

  sidebarPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("car_ui"),
    uiOutput("plots")
  )
)
)
```

2- Add this code in the first `observeEvent`, just above the `output$plots`

```
output$car_ui <- renderUI({

      lengthY <- length(unique(d()$curveNumber))
      if (lengthY<1){
        plot_output_list <- list()
      }
      else{
        plot_output_list <- lapply(1:lengthY, function(i) {
          plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
          plotlyOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
        })
      }

      car <- bs_carousel(id = "carousel", use_indicators = TRUE)
      Reduce(bs_append, plot_output_list, init=car)
    })
```

Also note you don't have to put all your calculations (lengthY...) in a `reactive`